# What is the meaning of "sweep overhead"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

> Here again the formal-logical overstraining of a relative truth-factor leads to the theoretical and practical annihilation of the concept in question. For so rigid a formulation of responsibility is identical with complete irresponsibility. We did not need to be politicians or Marxists to see that. A master of the “psychology of depths,” Dostoevsky, often said that extreme rigid forcing of moral principles and moral decisions generally has no influence on men’s actions. They **sweep overhead**, and the men who act on them have weaker moral guidance than would be the case if they had no principles at all. In the shadow of the rigorous pitiless feeling of responsibility, extending to the point of suicide, it is easy to commit one villainy after another with frivolous cynicism.
>
> *Existentialism*, Georg Lukács 1949

What is the meaning of "sweep overhead" in the above paragraph?

Comment: What sweeps overhead? We're missing the critical previous sentence.

Comment: *Planes*, *clouds*,  or *birds* sweeping overhead has a very different meaning a more abstract concept.

Comment: Look for the subject of the verb *sweep*.

Comment: Explaining the specific role that the metaphor of sweeping overhead has in this text requires an **extensive** discussion of the **subject matter** of this text. The text is written for a relatively specialised audience, so a full understanding of it requires a certain theoretical background; it is not just a matter of the mastery of English language.

Answer (score 0):

Lukács appears to be constructing a metaphor (or is it a simile without the “like”?) for the idea that rigid moral principles do not influence men’s actions [my simplification].

My schoolboy analysis (I used to do this for English GCE ‘O’ level) would be:

> Just as birds might sweep overhead*, causing a temporary distraction
> but leaving the observer unaffected after they have gone, so extreme rigid
> moral principles (according to Dostoevsky) perturb a man for a moment,
> but have vanished from his mind when he comes to decide on a course of action.

But I’m long out of practice (and I don’t do philosophy).

*Fly low and swiftly above and past one